# android dynamic plot using Achartengine

Tags: android, plot, achartengine

i m new to android. I m using Achartengine to plot a dynamic graph reading values from a binary file. Given below is my code.I want to have a dynamic running graph, in which values are being updated regularly. For this i tries to do it with and without a timer. But every time i am getting the graph with the final values when the last values have been updated. I mean i m getting a static graph after all the updates have been done. I can't figure out how to correct this. I am using the emulator to test the code. Could there be some problem with the emulator or something wrong with my code ? Thanks in advance

code without timer :

```
public class RandomActivity extends Activity {
private XYMultipleSeriesDataset eeg1 = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer_eeg1 = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
private XYSeries series1;
private GraphicalView view_eeg1;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

renderer_eeg1.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
renderer_eeg1.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
renderer_eeg1.setLabelsTextSize(15);
renderer_eeg1.setLegendTextSize(15);
renderer_eeg1.setMargins(new int[] {20, 30, 15, 0});
renderer_eeg1.setAxesColor(Color.BLUE);
renderer_eeg1.setXTitle("Time");
renderer_eeg1.setChartTitle("eeg1");
XYSeriesRenderer seriesrenderer1 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
seriesrenderer1.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
renderer_eeg1.addSeriesRenderer(seriesrenderer1); 
series1= new XYSeries("eeg1");
eeg1.addSeries(series1);
int a;
int b;
add();

for(int r=0;r<=600;r++){

   if(r%2==0){
      a=1;
      b=-1;
   }
   else{
      a=-1;
      b=1;
   }

   series1.add(r, a);
       if(r<=50){
      renderer_eeg1.setXAxisMax(50);
       }
       else if(r>50){
          double maxX = series1.getMaxX();
      double minX = maxX - 50;
          renderer_eeg1.setXAxisMin(minX);
       }
       view_eeg1.repaint();
}
}


protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();  
if (view_eeg1== null) {
LinearLayout layout_eeg1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart1);
view_eeg1= ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, eeg1, renderer_eeg1);
layout_eeg1.addView(view_eeg1,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,  LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
} else {
 view_eeg1.repaint();}
}

}
```

code with timer :

```
public class RandomActivity extends Activity {
private XYMultipleSeriesDataset eeg1 = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer_eeg1 = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
private XYSeries series1;
private GraphicalView view_eeg1;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

renderer_eeg1.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
renderer_eeg1.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
renderer_eeg1.setLabelsTextSize(15);
renderer_eeg1.setLegendTextSize(15);
renderer_eeg1.setMargins(new int[] {20, 30, 15, 0});
renderer_eeg1.setAxesColor(Color.BLUE);
renderer_eeg1.setXTitle("Time");
renderer_eeg1.setChartTitle("eeg1");
XYSeriesRenderer seriesrenderer1 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
seriesrenderer1.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
renderer_eeg1.addSeriesRenderer(seriesrenderer1); 
series1= new XYSeries("eeg1");
eeg1.addSeries(series1);
int a;
int b;
add();

for(int r=0;r<=600;r++){

      Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }
        };


   if(r%2==0){
      a=1;
      b=-1;
   }
   else{
      a=-1;
      b=1;
   }

   series1.add(r, a);
       if(r<=50){
      renderer_eeg1.setXAxisMax(50);
       }
       else if(r>50){
          double maxX = series1.getMaxX();
      double minX = maxX - 50;
          renderer_eeg1.setXAxisMin(minX);
       }
       view_eeg1.repaint();
}
}


protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();  
if (view_eeg1== null) {
LinearLayout layout_eeg1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart1);
view_eeg1= ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, eeg1, renderer_eeg1);
layout_eeg1.addView(view_eeg1,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,  LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
} else {
 view_eeg1.repaint();}
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You repaint before your chart is actually added to the view so it doesn't get painted.
2. Your code is not inside the threads you are creating.
3. You are creating 600 threads but you run none of them.
4. Your onResume code looks like you think onResume is called many times which is usually false.
5. Activity does not have any Add() function, do you have one what is that supposed to do?

I think this will work better:

```
public class RandomActivity extends Activity {
private XYMultipleSeriesDataset eeg1 = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer_eeg1 = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
private XYSeries series1;
private GraphicalView view_eeg1;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    renderer_eeg1.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
    renderer_eeg1.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    renderer_eeg1.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    renderer_eeg1.setLegendTextSize(15);
    renderer_eeg1.setMargins(new int[] {20, 30, 15, 0});
    renderer_eeg1.setAxesColor(Color.BLUE);
    renderer_eeg1.setXTitle("Time");
    renderer_eeg1.setChartTitle("eeg1");
    XYSeriesRenderer seriesrenderer1 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    seriesrenderer1.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    renderer_eeg1.addSeriesRenderer(seriesrenderer1); 
    series1= new XYSeries("eeg1");
    eeg1.addSeries(series1);
    int a;
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                for(int r=0;r<=600;r++){
                    sleep(500);
                    if(r%2==0){
                        a=1;
                    }
                    else{
                        a=-1;
                    }
                    series1.add(r, a);
                    if(r<=50){
                        renderer_eeg1.setXAxisMax(50);
                    }
                    else if(r>50){
                        double maxX = series1.getMaxX();
                        double minX = maxX - 50;
                        renderer_eeg1.setXAxisMin(minX);
                    }
                    view_eeg1.repaint();

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }
        };
    timer.start()
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();  
            if (view_eeg1== null) {
                LinearLayout layout_eeg1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart1);
                view_eeg1= ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, eeg1, renderer_eeg1);
                layout_eeg1.addView(view_eeg1,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                } else {
                view_eeg1.repaint();}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot man, it worked:)......but when i try to reduce the sleep time(i.e make the graph move faster) the application crashes. i am able to go till 300ms, below that it just crashes. any solution ? Another thing, when i try this with displaying 14 graphs on a single screen(i know it's too bulky) it goes for a while and then crashes. could you please explain why is that ? Is achartengine not capable of doing some fast processing ?

Comment: I would guess it is a raise condition, the view_eeg1.repaint() is run before view_eeg1 is instantiated when you lower the sleep. You should either move the instantiation to onCreate or add a control to check if it is before repainting.

Comment: Hi, Before we run this code, we need to add the achart engine API(Jar file) in our app. you can download the api file [here](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/detail?name=achartengine-1.0.0.jar&can=2&q=)